URL Detection and Exit Dialog in Cobalt YouTube
There are two things I am trying to do in Cobalt YouTube Android app:

Detect the current URL which is open, e.g. https://youtube.com/tv if in home tab, https://youtube.com/tv/movies for movies tab, etc. in starboard/android/shared/application_android.cc.
Trigger the exit dialog when exiting YouTube from above mentioned file.

I have not been able to find any such dialogs in the cobalt code. On compiling the devel or debug build, it simply exits without any dialogs. Neither did I find any functions to show me the URL in android starboard port of cobalt. I want to be able to exit the app on back key event when user is in home window, which is why I want to detect the URL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
